# Ubuntu Boot Problem - No Choice Menu - Still asking to reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I'm new to Linux. I followed the instructions on the internet to install Ubuntu 18.04. on my computer alongside Windows 10 using a USB stick. It was successful... but I have one problem.

While starting up the computer (removing USB), it boots straight into Windows 10. Every time I put the USB drive back in, I'm asked to "**Try ubuntu without installing**" or **reinstall** Ubuntu. There is no choice menu between Ubuntu and Windows.

If I want to get the GNU Grub screen with a choice menu I have to exit it, then go to the Boot Manager, choose Ubuntu and ufff, there is a menu choice. I followed the instructions for installing boot-repair, changing the boot order in BIOS and nothing has changed. 
My **BOOT order** looks like that:

- USB Diskette on Key / USB Hard Disk
- OS Boot Manager
- USB CD/DVD ROM Drive
- ! Network Adapter

I can't find in OS Boot Manager the option "Ubuntu", unfortunately.
I have Legacy Support and Secure Boot **Disabled**.
Please, let me know what else I can do to fix this problem. I want to have a menu choice between Ubuntu and Windows after starting up the computer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Did you maybe leave the USB stick plugged in when restarting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](/q/88384/175814), specifically [Web-E’s answer](/a/182863/175814).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If the above doesn’t help could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: @Videonauth I did leave the USB stick plugged in when restarting because when I didn't do so it boots straight into Windows like Ubuntu doesn't exist on my computer.